# Oracle self join starting with minimum value for each partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------
   A       1    VAL1
   A       2    VAL2
   A       4    VAL3
   B       2    VAL4
   B       4    VAL5
   B       5    VAL6
```

And I would like to obtain this output:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------
   A       1    VAL1
   A       2    VAL2
   A       3    NULL
   B       2    VAL4
   B       3    NULL
   B       4    VAL6
```

Logic:

with the smallest COL2 value for each partition of COL1, take the following 3 numbers and, if the combination COL1 and COL2 present in the first table, show COL3 and NULL otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a good example of what `PARTITIONED OUTER JOIN` was created for: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ce39f6ba2c28682c20b83c45802c05cd)

```
with top3 as (
  select *
  from (
    select
       col1, col2, col3
      ,min(col2)over(partition by col1) min_col2
      ,col2 - min(col2)over(partition by col1) + 1 as rn
    from t
  )
  where col2 < min_col2 + 3
)
select 
   top3.col1
  ,r3.n as col2
  ,top3.col3
from
   top3 
     partition by (col1)
     right join 
      (select level n from dual connect by level<=3) r3
       on r3.n=top3.rn;
```

As you can see, the first step is to get top3 and then just use `partition by (col1) right join r3`, where r3 is just generator of 3 rows.

Results:

```
COL1        COL2 COL3
----- ---------- ----
A              1 VAL1
A              2 VAL2
A              3
B              1 VAL4
B              2
B              3 VAL5

6 rows selected.
```

Note, this approach allows you to scan your table *just once*!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just realised I messed up with the requirement on incremental numbers so I have asked an amended question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744442/oracle-self-join-starting-with-minimum-value-yearmonths-for-each-partition

Comment: @banana_99 just use `date` functions, for example: `col2 + numtoyminterval(1, 'month'))`

Comment: So, do you mean replace all instances of col2 with that formula?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see. Here is the table

```
select * from t order by col1, col2;

COL1        COL2 COL3
----- ---------- -----
A              1 VAL1
A              2 VAL2
A              4 VAL3
B              2 VAL4
B              4 VAL5
B              5 VAL6

6 rows selected
```

and now let's try to apply the described logic

```
with offsets as
 (select level - 1 offset from dual connect by level <= 3),
smallest_col2 as
 (select col1, min(col2) min_col2 from t group by col1)
select sc2.col1, sc2.min_col2 + o.offset col2, t.col3
  from smallest_col2 sc2
 cross join offsets o
  left join t
    on t.col1 = sc2.col1
   and t.col2 = sc2.min_col2 + o.offset
 order by 1, 2;

COL1        COL2 COL3
----- ---------- -----
A              1 VAL1
A              2 VAL2
A              3 
B              2 VAL4
B              3 
B              4 VAL5

6 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just realised I messed up with the requirement on incremental numbers so I have asked an amended question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744442/oracle-self-join-starting-with-minimum-value-yearmonths-for-each-partition

Comment: it's ok. I think you can still use any of the answers and just change "col2 + sth" expressions into "add_months(col2, sth)"

Comment: But what would then be my starting point like in here (select level - 1 offset from dual connect by level <= 3)? It would no longer be one anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Use a recursive CTE to get the `COL2`s from the min of each `COL1` up to the next 2 and then a left join to the table:

```
WITH cte(COL1, COL2, max_col2) AS (
  SELECT COL1, MIN(COL2), MIN(COL2) + 2
  FROM tablename
  GROUP BY COL1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT COL1, COL2 + 1, max_col2
  FROM cte
  WHERE COL2 < max_col2
)
SELECT c.COL1, c.COL2, t.COL3
FROM cte c LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.COL1 = c.COL1 AND t.COL2 = c.COL2
ORDER BY c.COL1, c.COL2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3a158b5e2acef04dc74db9180778749).

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for having edited the question, I just realised I messed up with the incremental numbers requirement :(

Comment: @banana_99 if your requirement is different you should ask a new question and not edit with something new which invalidates all the answers that you already got.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just realised I messed up with the requirement on incremental numbers so I have asked an amended question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744442/oracle-self-join-starting-with-minimum-value-yearmonths-for-each-partition

Answer (score 2):

The partitioned outer join, already demonstrated in Sayan's answer, is probably the best approach for that part of the assignment (data densification).

For the first part, in Oracle 12.1 and higher you can use the `match_recognize` clause:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from   this_table
         match_recognize(
           partition by col1
           order     by col2
           measures  col2 - a.col2 + 1 as rn
           all rows  per match
           pattern   ( ^ a b* )
           define    b as col2 <= a.col2 + 2
         ) 
       partition by (col1)
       right outer join
       (select level as rn from dual connect by level <= 3)  using (rn)
;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just realised I messed up with the requirement on incremental numbers so I have asked an amended question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744442/oracle-self-join-starting-with-minimum-value-yearmonths-for-each-partition

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the "recursive WITH clause"

```sql
With rws_numbered (COL1, COL2, COL3, rn) as (
select COL1, COL2, COL3
  , row_number()over(order by col1, col3) rn
from Your_table
)
, cte ( COL1, COL2, COL3, rn ) as (
  select COL1, COL2, COL3, rn
  from rws_numbered
  where rn = 1
  union all
  select 
      t.COL1
    , case when t.col1 = c.col1 then c.col2 + 1 else t.col2 end COL2
    , t.COL3    
    , t.rn
  from rws_numbered t 
  join cte c 
    on c.rn + 1 = t.rn 
)
select COL1, COL2, case when exists (select null from Your_table t where t.COL1 = cte.COL1 and t.COL2 = cte.COL2) then COL3 else null end COL3
from cte
order by 1, 2
;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=06ec0a17f043a70411dc5cbdded52b53)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have just realised I messed up with the requirement on incremental numbers so I have asked an amended question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744442/oracle-self-join-starting-with-minimum-value-yearmonths-for-each-partition