# Oracle self join starting with minimum value (yearmonths) for each partition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------
   A    202011  VAL1
   A    202012  VAL2
   A    202205  VAL3
   B    202111  VAL4
   B    202201  VAL5
   B    202202  VAL6


COL1    COL2    COL3
--------------------
   A    202011  VAL1
   A    202012  VAL2
   A    202101  NULL
   B    202111  VAL4
   B    202112  NULL
   B    202201  VAL5
```

EDIT: I have the dates too if that's easier to play with than the ISO weeks.

Logic:

with the smallest COL2 value for each partition of COL1, take the following 3 yearmonths (YYYYMM) and, if the combination COL1 and COL2 present in the first table, show COL3 and NULL otherwise.

I have attempted to create this query to replicate what I would need in terms of adding up months, but not sure if it will be useful though.

```
WITH level_aux ( lev ) AS (
    SELECT
        to_number('2020'
                  || lpad(level, 2, 0)) + 7 - 1
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        level <= 12
), level_final AS (
    SELECT
        lev,
        substr(lev, 1, 4) +
            CASE
                WHEN mod(substr(lev, 5, 2), 13) = 0 THEN
                    1
                ELSE
                    0
            END
        ||
            CASE
                WHEN substr(lev, 5, 2) < 13 THEN
                    lpad(mod(substr(lev, 5, 2), 13), 2, 0)
                ELSE
                    lpad(mod(substr(lev, 5, 2), 13) + 1, 2, 0)
            END
        h
    FROM
        level_aux
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    level_final;
```

Comment: just use `date` functions, for example: `col2 + numtoyminterval(1, 'month'))`

Comment: "I have dates too if that's easier than the ISO weeks" What **ISO weeks** are you talking about? I don't see any in your data. What "dates"? Do you mean you don't have YYYYMM in `col2`, that is calculated based on dates? Are your initial values (`col3`) actually the result of previous processing, perhaps aggregation by month? You probably don't even need to do that, you can do **everything** in a single step. But you need to explain the actual problem, not a made-up one.

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - please run `select date '2020-01-31' + numtoyminterval(1, 'month') from dual;` to see why adding **interval year to month** to a date is not such a good idea in general. Much better: `add_months(col2, 1)`.

Comment: @mathguy I know about this and, as far as I remember, I even wrote about this to you somewhere here... but in this case OP is talking about 1st day of months.

Comment: The OP has strings representing months in format YYYYMM - which can indeed be converted to dates with that format model, resulting in the first day of the month by default. But he is also offering to show us the raw dates - I believe that means the `col2` he shared with us is not the actual data. If he then generalizes to adding interval to dates in that case, he may run into errors. In general, I believe, one should always use `add_months()` - there is no case when using interval in that place (adding to a date) would have any advantage over `add_months`.

Comment: Hey, come on... add_months has own nuances, just try `add_months(date'2021-02-28',1)`. Any time you operate with "months" you should define/provide exact rules you want to use. So the choice between intervals or add_months or even +/-number depends on the rules you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Use `MIN()` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       (case when col2 < add_months(min(col2) over (partition by col1), 3)
             then col3
        end) as imputed_col3
from t;
```

Note:  If `col2` is not a date, you can convert it:

```
select t.*,
       (case when to_date(col2, 'YYYYMM') < add_months(min(to_date(col2, 'YYYYMM')) over (partition by col1), 3)
             then col3
        end) as imputed_col3
from t;
```

Comment: But if the entry has no match I still need to show a NULL.

Comment: @banana_99 . . . This doesn't filter out any rows.  If there is no match, it should return `NULL` for the last column.

Comment: That's not what the OP is saying. What he is saying is that if a certain month is missing for a `col1` value (missing **row**, not `null` value in `col3`), such an additional row should be created. Partitioned outer join - this was discussed in an earlier question the same poster had earlier today; the rest of the question is different, but the "partitioned outer join" part is the same as in his older question.